# How to handle "resend" email in SNS and SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs, serverless-framework, amazon-sns, serverless, aws-serverless

I have an SNS topic called `onboard-user`. A lot of microservices subscribe to this topic

for ex:

Emai microservice - to send the email

System preferences microservice -To set the defaults

There is a queue in these microservices that subscribes to the `onboard-user` SNS topic.

Now, if the email to the user needs to be resent, how should it be handled? `onboard-user` should not get a new message in that case as that has its own purpose and we would not want all of the microservices listening to it to be notified.

Having an alternate SNS topic for send emails doesn't sound like such a good idea and an overkill. what's the right way to handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would an email need to be resent? Due to a transient error or due to some business logic initiated by an end user? The solution depends on the problem. I would argue that if you detect the case where a message needs to be recent that you either: (A) maintain separate resend email SQS queue OR (B) put a new message on the existing email queue with a field indicating that this is a resend.

Since SQS is pretty cheap, I could lean towards (A).

Comment: Currently, the queue is basically just subscribed to the SNS topic so were not pushing to the queue so far.  So If I am understanding you currently, it should be that a separate queue for "resends"  and logic to push the message to the queue. Is that right? Option B is not really for us as we cannot put the "resend" message to the SNS topic to which the email queue is subscribed to.

Comment: The resend email is business logic initiated by the end-user @Andrew White

Comment: "So If I am understanding you currently" - you do. "cannot put the 'resend' message to the SNS topic" - no but you can still push message directly to the existing queue via the SQS APIs. A queue isn't restricted to a single source of messages.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That sounds doable but I am a little apprehensive since that will sort of create coupling between the microservice  that triggers the resend and the email microservice that owns the queue

Answer (score -1):

If my understanding is correct, you have single SNS topic to do multiple processing and that's why multiple microservices are listening to it. Please correct, if that is incorrect.
If that is the case, the better option is to:
a. Segregate email processing - keep a separate SNS topic for email purpose e.g. 'inform-user' and use it for retrying
b.  If you can't segregate, then the only option in above scenario is to have "state" in the message itself. That means having an attribute in the message to indicate that it is for "retrying" and then the listener microservice should process accordingly.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question at all.